# bxSlider showing white background in phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, bxslider

I am using bxSlider for a simple slider. When displayed on the browser the bxSlider works perfectly but when debugging in phonegap the slider displays a white background with the slider navigational arrows.

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Cordova and JqueryMobile. In iOS bxSlider worked like a charm, but in android I was getting the same, blank screen with the arrows like you.

I think it is related to the $(document).ready() function. In some way, in Android the DOM is not well organized, so bxSlider can't make his work and hides all your images.

If this is your case, you can solve calling the bxSlider init function in other event of jquerymobile, after document ready one. Something like this should work:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="slider">
        <script>
            $('#slider').on('pageshow', function(){
                 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                     onSliderLoad: function(){
                          $('.slider_wrapper').css('visibility', 'visible');
                     }    
             });
        </script>
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Slider page</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slider_wrapper">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="img/slider/business-h-c-480-640-10.jpg" /></li>
                /** Your images here **/
                <li><img src="img/slider/business-h-c-480-640-7.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Remember to put in your css file a rule to hide the slider wrapper, like:

```
.slider_wrapper{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is because you are calling the init slider when page shows, so the final user should see your images unformatted and a brief moment after the slider working. You should not write display: none, because the slider wouldn't work either.

Hope this make the trick for you.